# Error templating home page: html/template: "lobby-create-page" is undefined { golang }

Tags: go, templates, web-applications

```
func init() {
var templateParseError error
pageTemplates, templateParseError = template.ParseFS(templateFS, "templates/*")
if templateParseError != nil {
    panic(templateParseError)
}
```

Here is the function which showing error
I tried every solution available but it didn't fixing.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.